# I don't understand how to to check the condition of query in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write following query but I am not very comfortable with the SQL.
I isolated the insert and update and it works but I can't make the conditional control.
I do not understand why it always fails, can any help me?

```
IF (SELECT * FROM Infopoints WHERE name = @name) THEN 
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Infopoints (idInfopoint, createdAt, updatedAt, name) 
      VALUES(@idInfopoint, @createdAt, @updatedAt, @name)
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      UPDATE Infopoints SET updatedAt = @updatedAt WHERE name = @name;
    END;
ENDIF;";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `on duplicate key update`.  I think the logic is:

```
INSERT INTO Infopoints (idInfopoint, createdAt, updatedAt, name) 
      VALUES(@idInfopoint, @createdAt, @updatedAt, @name)
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updatedAt = @updatedAt;
```

For this to work, you need a unique index on `name`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_infopoints_name ON infopoints(name);
```

The logic that you want for the `IF` is:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Infopoints WHERE name = @name) THEN 
. . .
```

However, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the `IF` condition is off, try this instead:

```
If Not Exists (Select * From Infopoints Where Name = @Name) 
Begin
    Insert Into Infopoints
                (idInfopoint, createdAt, updatedAt, name) 
    Values      (@idInfopoint, @createdAt, @updatedAt, @name)
End
Else
Begin
    Update  Infopoints
    Set     UpdatedAt = @UpdatedAt
    Where   Name = @Name
End
```